# Submit enquiry form with PHP file

Tags: php

I'm new at this, could someone have a look at my sendresults script and tell me where I have gone wrong?

The form is a seperate HTML doc, the .php is uploaded to root directory, I have a confirm and error.html in the root too. The form when submitted comes back up blank. 
Here is the script;(I have taken out the complete business website urls)

```
<?php

// Subject 
$subject = "Results from Enquiry form";
//  form information will be sent to.
$mailto = 'my email';
//form url
$formurl = "http://www....";
// redirect after form is processed.
$confirmurl = 'http://www.....';
//redirect for errors
$errorurl = "http://www....";

$email_is_required =1;
$name_is_required =1;
$comments_is_required = 1;
$telephone_is_required = 1;
$uself = 0;
$forcelf = 0;
$use_envsender = 0;
$use_sendmailfrom = 0;
$smtp_server_win = "";
$use_webmaster_email_for_from = 0;
$use_utf8 = 1;

define ('MAX_LINE_LENGTH', 900 );
$headersep = $uself ? "\n":"\r\n";
$content_nl = $forcelf ? "\n" : (defined('PHP_EOL') ? PHP_EOL : "\n");
$content_type = $use_utf8 ? 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' : 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"';
if ($use_sendmailfrom) {
    ini_set('sendmail_from', $mailto);
}

$envsender = "-f$mailto";
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ?
    $_POST['name']: $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];  
    $bushwalking = $_POST['bushwalking'];
    $trout_fishing = $_POST['trout_fishing'];
    $canoeing = $_POST['canoeing'];
    $accommodation = $_POST['accommodation'];
    $corporate_events = $_POST['corporate_events'];
    $guests_for_accomm = $_POST['guests_for_accomm'];
    $stay = $_POST['stay'];
    $dday = $_POST['dday'];
    $dMonth = $_POST['dMonth'];
    $dYear = $_POST['dYear'];
    $http_referrer = getenv ("HTTP_REFERER" );

if (!isset($_POST['email']))  {
    header("Location: $formurl" );
    exit;
}
if (($email_is_required && (empty($email) || !preg_match('/@/', $email))) || ($name_is_required && empty($name)) || ($comments_is_required && empty($comments))) {
           header("Location: $errorurl" );
           exit;
}
if ( preg_match("/[\r\n]/", $name) || preg_match ("/[\r\n]/", $email) ) {header( "Location: $errorurl" );
exit;
}
if (empty($email)) {
    $email = $mailto ;
}
$fromemail = $use_webmaster_email_for_from ? $mailto : $email;
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc' ) && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes ($comments);
}
$messageproper = "Ths message was sent from:" . $content_nl . 
                 "http_referer" . $content_nl .
                 "-----------------------------------------------------------------
                 " . $content_nl .
                 "Name of sender: $name" . $content_nl .
                 "Address of sender: $address" . $content_nl .
                 "City of sender: $city" . $content_nl .
                 "State of sender: $state" . $content_nl .
                 "Postcode of sender: $postcode" . $content_nl .
                 "Telephone of sender: $telephone" . $content_nl .
                 "Email of sender: $email" . $content_nl .
                 "Required information: $bushwalking, $trout_fishing, $canoeing, $accommodation, $corporate_events " . $content_nl .
                 "Number of guest: $guests_for_accomm" . $content_nl . 
                 "Length of stay: $stay" . $content_nl .
                 "Date if arrival: $dday, dMonth, dYear" . $content_nl . 
                 "-------------------------------------------COMMENTS--------------------------------------" . $content_nl . $contents_nl . 
                 wordwrap($comments, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, $content_nl, true ) . $content_nl . $content_nl . "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" . $content_nl ;
                 $headers = "From:\"$name\" <$fromemail>" . 
                 $headersep . "Reply-To:\"$name\"<$email>" .
                 $headersep . "X-Mailer: chfeedback.php 2.16.2" . 
                 $headersep . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $headersep . $content_type ;
if ($use_envsender) {
         if(mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, $headers, $envsender))
         {
          echo("Location: $confirmurl");
}}
else  {
          echo( "Location: $errorurl" );   
}
?>

Here is the html
<body>
<div id="apDiv1">
<div class="form"><form id="enquiry_form" name="enquiry_form" method="post" action="/sendresults.php" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="return exec()">
  <table width= "420" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
   <tr><td height="15" colspan="2"></td>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Please enter details for your enquiry below<br/><br/>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="25%" align="left">
         Name:</td>
          <td width="75%"><label><input name="name" type="text" class="content_fieldset" id="name" value=""/>*
          </label></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Address:</td>
          <td><label><input name="address" id="address" type="text" class="content_fieldset" value="" /></label></td>
          </tr>
       <tr><td>City:</td>
          <td><label><input name="city" id="city" type="text" class="content_fieldset" value="" /></label></td>
          </tr>
        <tr><td>State:</td>
          <td><label><input name="state" id="state" type="text" class="content_fieldset" value="" /></label></td>
          </tr>
        <tr><td>Postcode:</td>
       <td><label><input name="postcode" id="postcode" type="text" class="content_fieldset" value="" /></label></td></tr>
          </tr>
      <tr><td>Telephone:</td>
          <td><label><input name="telephone" type="text" class="content_fieldset" id="telephone" value="" />*</label></td>
          </tr>
     <tr><td>E-mail:</td>
          <td><label><input name="email" type="text" class="content_fieldset" id="email" value=""/>*</label></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="right">* Required fields</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td height="15" colspan="2"></td></tr> 
           <tr><td colspan="2"> What would you like information about?</td>
           </tr>
         <tr><td height="10" colspan="2"></td></tr>
          <tr><td width=10%><label><input type="checkbox" name="bushwalking" id="bushwalking" value="bushwalking" checked="checked" /></label></td><td>Bush walking</td>         </tr>
          <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="trout_fishing" id="trout_fishing" value="trout_fishing" /></label></td><td>Trout Fishing</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="canoeing" id="canoeing" value="canoeing" /></label></td><td>Canoeing</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="corporate_events" id="corporate_events" value="corporate_events" /></label></td><td>Corporate Events</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="accommodation" id="accommodation" value="accommodation" checked="checked" /></label></td><td>Accommodation</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td height="20" colspan="2"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td width="40%">No. of Guests requiring accommodation:</td>
          <td><label><input name="guests_for_accomm" type="text" id="guests_for_accomm" size="3" value="" /></label></td>
          <tr><td height="15" colspan="2"></td> 
          </tr>
          <tr><td>Length of Stay:</td><td><label>
          <select name="stay" id="stay">
            <option>0 nights</option>
            <option>1 night</option>
            <option>2 nights</option>
            <option>3 nights</option>
            <option>4 nights</option>
            <option>5 nights</option>
            <option>6 nights</option>
            <option>7 nights</option>
            <option>8 nights</option>
            <option>9 nights</option>
            <option>10 nights</option>
          </select>
          </label></td>
          </tr>
           <tr><td height="15" colspan="2"></td>
          <tr><td width="35%">Date of Arrival:</td>
          <td><select name="dday" id="dday">
            <option value="01" >1</option>
            <option value="02" >2</option>
            <option value="03" >3</option>
            <option value="04" >4</option>
            <option value="05" >5</option>
            <option value="06" >6</option>
            <option value="07" >7</option>
            <option value="08" >8</option>
            <option value="09" >9</option>
            <option value="10" >10</option>
            <option value="11" >11</option>
            <option value="12" >12</option>
            <option value="13" >13</option>
            <option value="14" >14</option>
            <option value="15" >15</option>
            <option value="16" >16</option>
            <option value="17" >17</option>
            <option value="18" >18</option>
            <option value="19" >19</option>
            <option value="20" >20</option>
            <option value="21" >21</option>
            <option value="22" >22</option>
            <option value="23" >23</option>
            <option value="24" >24</option>
            <option value="25" >25</option>
            <option value="26" >26</option>
            <option value="27" >27</option>
            <option value="28" >28</option>
            <option value="29" >29</option>
            <option value="30" >30</option>
            <option value="31" >31</option>
          </select>
          <select name="dMonth" id="dMonth">
            <option value="01" >January</option>
            <option value="02" >February</option>
            <option value="03" >March</option>
            <option value="04" >April</option>
            <option value="05" >May</option>
            <option value="06" >June</option>
            <option value="07" >July</option>
            <option value="08" >August</option>
            <option value="09" >September</option>
            <option value="10" >October</option>
            <option value="11" >November</option>
            <option value="12" >December</option>
          </select>
          <select name="dYear" id="dYear">
            <option value="2012" >2013</option>
            <option value="2013" >2014</option>
            <option value="2014" >2015</option>
            <option value="2015" >2016</option>
            <option value="2016" >2017</option>
            <option value="2017" >2018</option>
          </select></td>
          </tr>
       <tr><td height="15" colspan="2"></td>
          <tr><td>Comments:</td>
          <td><textarea name="comments" rows="6" cols="30" id="comments" ></textarea></td>
       </tr>
       <tr><td height="15" colspan="2"></td> 
          <tr><td colspan="2"><label><input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Submit"/> 
           <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></label></td>
        </tr> 
  </table>
</form></div></div>
```

Comment: A blank page usually indicates a fatal error. Check your error log.

Comment: what do you mean by a blank page?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Subject 
$subject = "Results from Enquiry form";
//  form information will be sent to.
$mailto = 'abc@eabc.com';
//form url
$formurl = "http://www.e247dubai.com";
// redirect after form is processed.
$confirmurl = 'http://www.e247dubai.com';
//redirect for errors
$errorurl = "http://www.e247dubai.com";

$email_is_required =1;
$name_is_required =1;
$comments_is_required = 1;
$telephone_is_required = 1;
$uself = 0;
$forcelf = 0;
$use_envsender = 1;
$use_sendmailfrom = 0;
$smtp_server_win = "";
$use_webmaster_email_for_from = 0;
$use_utf8 = 1;
define ('MAX_LINE_LENGTH', 900 );
$headersep = $uself ? "\n":"\r\n";
$content_nl = $forcelf ? "\n" : (defined('PHP_EOL') ? PHP_EOL : "\n");
$content_type = $use_utf8 ? 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' : 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"';
if ($use_sendmailfrom) {
    ini_set('sendmail_from', $mailto);
}

$envsender= "-f$mailto";
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ?  $_POST['name']: $_POST['name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$state=$_POST['state'];
$postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
$telephone=$_POST['telephone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];  
$bushwalking=$_POST['bushwalking'];
$trout_fishing=$_POST['trout_fishing'];
$canoeing=$_POST['canoeing'];
$accommodation=$_POST['accommodation'];
$corporate_events=$_POST['corporate_events'];
$guests_for_accomm=$_POST['guests_for_accomm'];
$stay=$_POST['stay'];
$dday=$_POST['dday'];
$dMonth=$_POST['dMonth'];
$dYear=$_POST['dYear'];
$http_referrer=getenv ("HTTP_REFERER" );
if (!isset($_POST['email']))  {
header("Location: $formurl" );
exit;
}
if (($email_is_required && (empty($email) || !preg_match('/@/', $email))) || ($name_is_required && empty($name)) || ($comments_is_required && empty($comments))) {
header("Location: $errorurl" );
exit;
}
if ( preg_match("/[\r\n]/", $name) || preg_match ("/[\r\n]/", $email) ) {header( "Location: $errorurl" );
exit;
}
if (empty($email)) {
$email = $mailto ;
}
$fromemail = $use_webmaster_email_for_from ? $mailto : $email;
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc' ) && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
 $comments = stripslashes ($comments);
}
//echo "name :".$name. " Address: ".$address." City:".$city;
$messageproper = "Ths message was sent from:" . $content_nl . 
"http_referer" . $content_nl .
"-----------------------------------------------------------------
" . $content_nl .
"Name of sender: $name" . $content_nl .
"Address of sender: $address" . $content_nl .
"City of sender: $city" . $content_nl .
"State of sender: $state" . $content_nl .
"Postcode of sender: $postcode" . $content_nl .
"Telephone of sender: $telephone" . $content_nl .
"Email of sender: $email" . $content_nl .
"Required information: $bushwalking, $trout_fishing, $canoeing, $accommodation, $corporate_events " . $content_nl .
"Number of guest: $guests_for_accomm" . $content_nl . 
"Length of stay: $stay" . $content_nl .
"Date if arrival: $dday, dMonth, dYear" . $content_nl . 
"-------------------------------------------COMMENTS--------------------------------------" . $content_nl . $contents_nl . 
wordwrap($comments, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, $content_nl, true ) . $content_nl . $content_nl . "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" . $content_nl ;
$headers = "From:\"$name\" <$fromemail>" . 
$headersep . "Reply-To:\"$name\"<$email>" .
$headersep . "X-Mailer: chfeedback.php 2.16.2" . 
$headersep . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $headersep . $content_type ;
if ($use_envsender) {
if(mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, $headers, $envsender))
{
echo ("Location: $confirmurl");
}}
else  {
echo( "Location: $errorurl" );   
}
?>
```

Try this.

Comment: I tried, took out all the white spaces, sorry, it did not work

Comment: OK I changed t0 =1, but still the form comes back up with blank fields, I don't get any confirmed.html or email, could it be something to do with  $headersep . "X-Mailer: chfeedback.php 2.16.2" Host is web city?

Comment: @user2042111 I copied same code and put it in my web I tried its working I got mail just check remove the all the whitespace. its really working

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. Yes I checked all the white space all through, but the same thing is happening. What do I try now?

Comment: does the form have to be in the root folder too? I have it in an enquiries folder as enquiries_lli.html

Comment: @user2042111 action="/sendresults.php" remove / action="sendresults.php"

Comment: I tried that too, moved the enquiries.html to the root, changed the URL's checked and still no go. Should we move to chat?

Comment: @user2042111 I tried it I upload It in my webserver can you give me your email id. i'll show you.

Comment: tashighcountry@skymesh.com.au

Comment: I am not allowed to chat you will have to email me